# node of xml with minidom used once

Tags: python, minidom

I want to use `xml.dom.minidom` to create XML. And want to use the same node to append into different parents. For example, "root", "node1" and "node2".

Target:

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <node2 \>
    </node1>
    <node2 \>
</root>
```

Real result:

```
<root>
    <node1 \>
    <node2 \>
</root>
```

Does it mean that a node just can be used once? Actually I want to not create another node, node12, that has the same attributes as node2.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.Document()

root = doc.createElement('root')
test1 = doc.createElement('test1')
test2 = doc.createElement('test2')

test1.appendChild(test2)

root.appendChild(test1)
root.appendChild(test2)

print(root.toprettyxml())
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: i use Node.cloneNode() to slove it. :)